# Why does Tomcat return a 500 error for 14 minutes and then continues again?

Tags: tomcat, jrubyonrails, honeywell

We have a JRuby on Rails applications which runs fine until a certain moment.

Then suddenly Tocmat returns a 500 error for about 14 minutes (we've put a redirect to the login page in the 500 error html page). The redirect to the login page returns a 500 error again (so there's a loop for about 14 minutes).

We have no idea what is causing this. From the logs there's not much to be found except for this:

> Started GET "/CyberTrack/fr/login?error=true" for 192.168.208.155 at
>   2015-11-05 17:34:12 +0100 2015-11-05 17:34:12 FATAL 
>   Encoding::CompatibilityError (incompatible encodings: UTF-8 and
>   Windows-1252): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:61:in
>   `log_info'

But if that's the cause, then why does the application suddenly start working again after 14 minutes...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you turn off the error redirection to see the traces produced by the very first error?

Answer (score 4):

Most probably it is encoding issue.

Regarding your question about 14mins to make it work again.

You can check your tomcat config about [workers](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) , worker retries, [worker intervals](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) and [workers timeout](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/timeouts.html)

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat error 500 throws when there may be one of following reason:

1. May be you are working with a non-Unicode/non-UTF-8 friendly editor. Rcreate this class from the scratch in a UTF-8 friendly editor.
2. There may be problem in web.xml
3. Check classes name e.g. FirstClass may be written as Firstclass
4. Check the $CATALINA/lib folder and make sure these JARs exits==> jasper-el.jar, jasper.jar, and jsp-api.jar
5. Check your $CATALINA/log/catalinaout.log file and read the reason
6. Add your database jar files into $CATALINA/lib folder
7. Also check your database and system encoding type as it may conflict with each other

Best regards